# WordPress Cookies and/or WooCommerce Session prevent caching

Tags: php, wordpress, session, caching, cookies

After reading multiple articles I still can't figure out if my site is using proper caching methods.

**Basic setup:**

- WordPress / WooCommerce
- Installed a custom plugin to change WC functionality
- Hoster: One-click wp hoster with a CDN and automated caching (was once in the list of recommended hosters (
  https://wordpress.org/hosting/ )

**user flow 1 on website:**

1. People come to the home page (nothing much happens here)
2. People then arrive at the subpage /quiz/ (a lot of input fields) which is created by my plugin. This page sets some cookies and also sets answers to quiz questions (gets cookie values) if the users went through the quiz some time before.
3. The user arrives at /results/ which is a autogenerated page based on the quiz answers from step 2. This page also loads and sets cookie values.
4. Also on the woocommerce checkout page we generate text blocks based on cookie values

**user flow 2 on website:**

1. A User arrives at /landingpage/. A WooCommerce session is set (sorry, I only found out WC sessions exist while having 90% of my plugin developed)
2. If the user goes to the checkout page, text pieces are adjusted based on the session values
3. Also, the page /results/ checks if the session is present

**Additionally:**
a menu item ("cart") is visible (that leads to the WC cart) only if the user completed the /quiz/ . This check is done with a cookie via php.

**My question:**
Does my use of cookies and sessions prevent my server/hoster from properly caching my website or subpages of the website? If so, which pages are properly cached and which not?

I am fine if the /quiz/ and /results/ and /checkout/ are not cached because content is dynamically created. But other pages like home, blog, etc. should be cached

Comment: p.s.: I know that my use of sessions and cookies is not according to best practices. This is why I ask the question :)

Comment: I see no single reason here why to care about caching. WordPress as WooCommerce use cookies and sessions widely and work perfectly on fully cached sites.

Comment: hi @KAGGDesign : based on this article here: https://wpengine.com/support/cookies-and-php-sessions/ and this one: https://mikejolley.com/2013/12/20/problems-with-cart-sessions-and-woocommerce/

Comment: I also found this here. Maybe it's also a solution to use transients whenever possible? https://scotch.io/tutorials/a-guide-to-transients-in-wordpress ... for example when users visit /results/ and the content displayed is basically the same that a user (maybe 5 days ago) generated?

Comment: It is already done for you. WordPress and WooCommerce use transients widely. And this is a good reading about transients https://pressjitsu.com/blog/transient-cache-alternatives/

Comment: Article of Mike Jolley is deadly old. It discusses WooCommerce 2.1. Active version now is 3.2

Comment: Article by WP Engine says that all problems are solved: "The correct method is to use the database to store session data. WooCommerce and other eCommerce solutions have already converted to using this method over traditional PHP Sessions"

Comment: Summarizing, I would recommend in your plugin to deal with cookies in js and update cached page via Ajax, which is never cached.

Comment: Thanks for the comments so far. I started moving the check, if cookie is present and based on that: show menu item "cart" from PHP to JS. I think with good results in page speed. Keep you posted